# AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory in iOS 9

Tags: swift, avplayer, avaudiosession

I want to play audio while the phone is in silent mode.

I can do this in >= iOS 10 with the following statement:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

But how do I do this for iOS 9? 
Xcode tells me that this statement is only available in iOS 10 or newer.

I tried the following but it is not working:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.2

Comment: Can you set your Swift Language Version to 4.0?

Comment: It is set to 4.2

Comment: Can you set it to 4.0?

Comment: OK, I have found what code works in Language Version 4.2. Try `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)`. I think you have no need to set `mode` when it is `AVAudioSessionModeDefault`. By the way does your `>= iOS 10` code compiles with Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.2) ?

Comment: this is not working. I updated my question with a screenshot to show the error message.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not setting the Swift Language Version to 4.2 successfully. When you set it to 4.2, the line `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)` does not compile. I will show you some combinations for each settings as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the method `setCategory` is rapidly changing in recent Xcodes & SDKs.

You need to find the right combination.

For Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.2, 5)

```
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            //Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.2,5)
            //Xcode 10.1 (Swift Language Version 4.2)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
        } else {
            //Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.2,5)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
        }
```

For Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.0)
or  Xcode 10.1 (Swift Language Version 4.0)

```
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            //Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.0)
            //Xcode 10.1 (Swift Language Version 4.0)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)
        } else {
            //Xcode 10.2 (Swift Language Version 4.0)
            //Xcode 10.1 (Swift Language Version 4.0)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
        }
```

(Unfortunately, I could not have found a way to call `setCategory` for iOS 9 with Xcode 10.1 (Swift Language Version 4.2).)

Anyway, please re-check your Swift Language Version setting:

[image]